# Dictionary not recognizing values: KeyError

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with hexadecimal values such as `0x11a` but the keys in my program are of the form  `b'\x01\x1a'`. How do I prevent a `KeyError` from occurring in this situation?

Comment: can you post what you tried?

Comment: Probably you use not `0x` prefix but something else which looks the same

Comment: it seems that `dict={};dict[b'\x01\x1a']=0x11a` doesn't throw any exception, `dict[b'\x01\x1a'] == 282`

Comment: @Gabrio: I think the OP is worried that he wants `b'\x00\x01\x1a'` to be mapped on the `b'\x01\x1'` as well. So if the hex is the same, the key should be the same.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think that this is not feasible, because since we are treating strings b'\x00\x01\x1a' isn't the same of b'\x01\x1' , am i doing wrong?

Comment: Of course it is feasible: you only have to normalize the key...

Answer (score 0):

in the following code i use the key-value pair that you have mentioned without getting any exception

```
dict={}
dict[b'\x01\x1a']=0x11a
print dict[b'\x01\x1a']==282 #the dec rappresentation of 0x11a
```

returns True